# Infinity loop (server down?) when I am trying to get page content with cURL (+ sending session_id)

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl

I have script [script `/inc/user_record.php`] (user on server A where I have to get json data [script `/inc/json.php`] (which is generated by another script on server A).

1 problem is: script print json output only if user logged in (so others users or guests can't read this message). I think that if I will send current user `session_id()` it will work fine.

I have next code on script `user_record.php`:

```
$json_url = "$SiteHost/inc/json.php?action=get_counters_data&period=6";
try {
    $ch = curl_init($json_url);
    $ses_id = session_id(); 
    $cookie = 'PHPSESSID='.$ses_id.';';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception thrown: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

This code have to work fine, but when I try to open page with script `user_record.php`, page will not load, browser will show he is trying to load (infinity loop?). Only server restart help solving the problem (or maybe time, I didn't try).

I tried next: I upload `json.php` script to `my-web-site.com` and logged in in it. I copied session id (firebug shows it for example) and pasted it into my local user_record script `user_record.php`. Look this code:

```
$json_url = "http://my-web-site.com/inc/json.php?action=get_counters_data&period=6";
try {
    $ch = curl_init($json_url);
    $ses_id = "session identificatory copied from website";
    $cookie = 'PHPSESSID='.$ses_id.';';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception thrown: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

All working fine now.

`json.php` code:

```
<?ob_start();
session_start();

$action = $_GET['action'];

if($_SESSION['UserAuthorized']) {
 #generating and printing json message in switch (get_counters_data path)
}
?>
```

Comment: If the current reqquest is with the same session id, that makes the session locked, meaning the other request will wait until the first script releases its lock, which will never happen. Calling a `session_write_close()` _before_ doing the curl request might solve this.

Comment: Where exactly I have to use this function? I need session and session data after doing this script. Will they work after? In what script I have to use this function and where? Can you explain.

Comment: curl does NOT throw errors. It's not OOP code. It'll return boolean false on failures. As for infinite loops, your code has no loops. so it cannot "loop" at all.

Comment: You use it, as I said, before the `curl` request. After your curl request, you can just call `session_start()` again if you've not generated any output yet (or: you can call it anyway, it will just generate a warning if you have already generated output). But: why are you doing this with an http request? Some function call / include or anything seems far more apt / portable / easy.

Comment: `session_write_close();

#making curl query

session_start();` — like this?

Comment: Yep, that'd do it (though I'd rewrite it to avoid the HTTP request entirely).